# How to Extract/Scrape a specific part of information from WikiData URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I have a list of webid that I want to scrape from WikiData website. Here are the two links as an example.

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q317521.jsonld
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q478214.jsonld

I only need the first set of "P31" from the URL. For the first URL, the information that I need will be `"wd:Q5"` and second URL will be `["wd:Q786820", "wd:Q167037", "wd:Q6881511","wd:Q4830453","wd:Q431289","wd:Q43229","wd:Q891723"]` and store them into a list.

[image: example]
When I use find and input "P31", I only need the first results out of all the results. The picture above illustrate it

The output will look like this.

```
info = ['wd:Q5',
        ["wd:Q786820", "wd:Q167037", "wd:Q6881511","wd:Q4830453","wd:Q431289","wd:Q43229","wd:Q891723"],
        ]
```

```
lst = ["Q317521","Q478214"]

for q in range(len(lst)):
  link =f'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/{q}.jsonld'
  page = requests.get(link)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

After that, I do not know how to extract the information from the first set of "P31". I am using `request, BeautifulSoup, and Selenium` libraries but I am wondering are there any better ways to scrape/extract that information from the URL besides using XPath or Class?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by `first set of "P31"` please? I am trying to understand how that applies to the second url resulting in the output you show above. Can there be more than one P31 in a response? Or more than one value associated with the P31 key?

Comment: @QHarr If you click on the URLs above, you will see a bunch of information, and if you use ```find and input P31```, it will report back a bunch of ```P31``` but I only need the first ```P31``` result out of all the results.

Comment: @QHarr I just updated the question with a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `requests` as you are getting a JSON response.

You can use a function which loops the relevant JSON nested object and exits at first occurrence of target key whilst appending the associated value to your list.

The loop variable should be the id to add into the url for the request.

```
import requests

lst = ["Q317521","Q478214"]
info = []

def get_first_p31(data):
    for i in data['@graph']:
        if 'P31' in i:
            info.append(i['P31'])
            break
    
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {"User-Agent": "Safari/537.36"}
    for q in lst:
        link =f'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/{q}.jsonld'
        try:
            r = s.get(link).json()
            get_first_p31(r)
        except:
            print('failed with link: ', link)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I am pretty new to Python so I am wondering what is the line ```s.headers``` does?

Comment: It simply impersonates using a browser by providing an user-agent identifier in the header (in this instance) See https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

Comment: Got it. So I can basically change it to any user-agent.

Comment: Yes and not sure it is required in this case. I added it out of habit. Some servers may be configured with lists of accepted/rejected user-agents btw.